# Why is 15.04 not updating?

Tags: apt, updates, 15.04

My 15.04 us not updating due to following errors:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-3.19.0-30-generic
 linux-signed-image-3.19.0-30-generic
 linux-signed-image-generic
 linux-signed-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Furthermore, I am getting errors form the fostware updator claimimng that there is not enough disk space in `/` when there are 89Gb free!

This is the full log:

```
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-3.19.0-26 linux-headers-3.19.0-26-generic
  linux-image-3.19.0-26-generic linux-image-extra-3.19.0-26-generic
  linux-signed-image-3.19.0-26-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up linux-image-extra-3.19.0-30-generic (3.19.0-30.33) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.19.0-30-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-30-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.19.0-30-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-30-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.19.0-30-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-30-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-30-generic

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-30-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.19.0-30-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-signed-image-3.19.0-30-generic:
 linux-signed-image-3.19.0-30-generic depends on linux-image-extra-3.19.0-30-generic (= 3.19.0-30.33); however:
  Package linux-image-extra-3.19.0-30-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-signed-image-3.19.0-30-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-signed-image-generic:
 linux-signed-image-generic depends on linux-signed-image-3.19.0-30-generic; however:
  Package linux-signed-image-3.19.0-30-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-signed-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-signed-generic:
 linux-signed-generic depends on linux-signed-image-generic (= 3.19.0.30.29); however:
  Package linux-signed-image-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linuxNo apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
                                                                No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
            No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                               -signed-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-3.19.0-30-generic
 linux-signed-image-3.19.0-30-generic
 linux-signed-image-generic
 linux-signed-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Add the output of `df` and the full error message.

Answer (score 0):

This error sometimes exists if you update via GUI.
Try to update from command line.

```
sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If this does not help try to free space. Uninstalling old linux kernels helps me.

```
sudo dpkg -l | grep linux
```

Then uninstall the old kernels. If you have only one, do not uninstall it!